# How to add anchor tag conditionally in ItemTemplate of Repeater

Tags: asp.net

I have Showing the Image Slider on page. To Display I have used the Repeater. Now I have not used anchor tag to image for every image. So Anchor tag is conditionally.
My code is

```
 <ItemTemplate>           
        <a  id="SliderLink">
             <img id="SliderImage" runat="server" alt="" />
         </a>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Now I always shows the image but every image not cover with a tag. How I achieved this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of databinding to the alt tag.

Assuming you have the alt-text somewhere in the datasource

Eg:

```
   <ItemTemplate>            
         <a  id="SliderLink"> 
         <img id="SliderImage" runat="server" alt='<%#Eval("youralttextfield")%>' /> 
     </a>
```

(Pay attention to single and double quotes here)